# OpenLayers - Map refusing to zoom to max extent

Tags: javascript, openlayers

If been changing round some OpenLayers code, and one side effect is that by Google Street base layer no longer displays a sensible map, but instead zooms out to a 3 x world view.  Nothing I put into the code which the api suggests should work does.

The same code - but rearranged - worked OK in the past (but didn't allow the bigger picture to work unfortunately)

I'm new to all this and way out of my comfort zone so a sanity check of the code would be much appreciated:

```
    function ProfileMap(mapName)
    {
        this.name = mapName;
        this.layers = [];

        // define Map options
        var mapoptions = {
                projection: mercator,
                units: "m",
                maxExtent: world
        };

        // define Base Layer
        var baselayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
                "Google Streets", 
                {numZoomLevels: 20, spehericalMercator: 2}
        );  


        this.init = function(mapdiv, keydiv)
        {
            var layerswitcher = new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher(
                    {div: document.getElementById(keydiv)}
            );      

            this.map = new OpenLayers.Map(mapdiv, mapoptions);
            this.map.addLayer(baselayer);
            this.map.setCenter(mapcenter);
            this.map.zoomToMaxExtent();

        };

        this.addMapLayer = function(layerName)
        {
            var layerid = this.layers.length;
            this.layers[layerid] = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers(layerName);
            this.map.addLayer(this.layers[layerid]);
        }

    }


    // Map actually created by a call to this function
    function createMap(mapName, div, keydiv, mapLayers)
    {
        mapName = new ProfileMap(mapName);
        mapName.init(div, keydiv);
        for(var i=0; i < mapLayers.length; i++)
        {
            mapName.addMapLayer(mapLayers[i]);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Could you please expose your page on a public URL so we can test it and get a better sense as to what the problem is? Or [get it working here](http://jsfiddle.net/XzKvP/). It will get your problem resolved a lot quicker.

Answer (score 0):

One thing it could be is that you've misspelled *sphericalMercator*. Also it takes in a boolean value, not numeric.

```
sphericalMercator: true
```

[Reference](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Google-js.html)

## Update #1:

Please change this:

```
var mapoptions = {
    projection: mercator,
    units: "m",
    maxExtent: world
};
```

for this:

```
var mapoptions = {
    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
    units: "m",
    maxExtent: world
};
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting that.  I have changed it in the code but it doesn't seem to have fixed the problem.  The odd thing is, those errors were cut and paste from working code!

Comment: @ChristianMayne : funny how working code is a relative thing. okay, try my update.

Comment: Thanks again.  Tried that - no change.  I've noticed that the 3 x world width fits to the size of the width of the div.  The height of the div is greater than 1 x world height.  Could it be something to do with the styling around the map, or should that make no difference?

Comment: Tell you the truth i'm having trouble understanding or visualizing your problem. Can you place your code in a public URL so we can see what exactly is going on?

Comment: OK - it might take me a while to strip out all the includes from the rest of the system etc.,  but bear with me and I'll let you know when I've done it